Insert host in to group_vars when playbook is run
How to set host1 in to group_vars database from playbook has run?
Thanks

add_host module – Add a host (and alternatively a group) to the ansible-playbook in-memory inventory, see the examples.

The short answer is: ansible.builtin.add_host
But, it's good to know that this change won't affect the current play. For example, given the inventory
shell> cat hosts
[database]
host2
host3

and the group_vars
shell> cat group_vars/database/main.yml 
test_var: database

The below play
- name: Play 1
  hosts: database

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: groups
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: test_var

gives as expected (abridged)
TASK [debug] ***
ok: [host2] => 
  groups:
    all:
    - host2
    - host3
    database:
    - host2
    - host3
    ungrouped: []

TASK [debug] ***
ok: [host2] => 
  test_var: database
ok: [host3] => 
  test_var: database

If you add the host host1 to the group database
    - add_host:
        name: host1
        groups: database

the added host will be reported in the group immediately
    - debug:
        var: groups
      run_once: true

gives (abridged)
  groups:
    all:
    - host1
    - host2
    - host3
    database:
    - host2
    - host3
    - host1
    ungrouped: []

But, the added host won't be included in the execution of the play
    - debug:
        var: test_var

gives (abridged) the same result as before
ok: [host2] => 
  test_var: database
ok: [host3] => 
  test_var: database

Refreshing the inventory doesn't help
    - meta: refresh_inventory

    - debug:
        var: test_var

still gives the same result
ok: [host2] => 
  test_var: database
ok: [host3] => 
  test_var: database

You have to start a new play to include the new host in the group
- name: Play 2
  hosts: database

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: test_var

gives
ok: [host2] => 
  test_var: database
ok: [host3] => 
  test_var: database
ok: [host1] => 
  test_var: database

The addition of the host to the group is not permanent. Only the current playbook is affected.


Example of a complete playbook for testing.
- name: Play 1
  hosts: database

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: groups
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: test_var

    - add_host:
        name: host1
        groups: database

    - debug:
        var: groups
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: test_var

    - meta: refresh_inventory

    - debug:
        var: test_var

- name: Play 2
  hosts: database

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: test_var


